# Old-Type JDBC URL Parsing using Python

Tags: python, oracle, parsing, jdbc

How can I parse a URL such as:

jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=1.1.1.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=server.name)))

Comment: This is technically not an "old type JDBC URL", it is a specific format of the Oracle TNSNAMES.ORA files that the Oracle JDBC driver also happens to support. See http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/tnsnames.htm#i500390.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Done.

```
a = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=1.1.1.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=server.name)))'
a = a.split('(')
host = a[4].replace(")","").replace("HOST=","")
port = a[5].replace(")","").replace("PORT=","")
s_name = a[7].replace(")","").replace("SERVICE_NAME=","")
url = host + ':' + port + '/' + s_name
print url
```

will print: 1.1.1.1:1521/server.name

Comment: This answer is unsafe as it assumes that HOST and PORT will be in the expected positions within the array when their locations are not predictable.